# WCF security at transport level or message level

Tags: wcf, security

i am new in wcf. i read msdn link for wcf securty for message level or transport level but unfortunately there was very small info regarding those security.

basically i am not being able to visualize how service will be secured when anyone select transport level security or message level security. i want to visualize how security works for the both.

so please discuss in detail what happen when user select transport level security and as well as message level security?

i got a small snippet for how to setup message level security as follows

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServicesBindings" receiveTimeout="00:00:30">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
      <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>

1) how many type of mode is possible want to know ?
2) how many option is available for clientCredentialType ?
```

looking for guidance. thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx ?